# R - How to create new table by adding a new column by extracting name of item from column name?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` with column names:

```
Machine1.workingTime, Machine2.workingTime, Machine3.workingTime,
Machine1.producedItems, Machine2.producedItems, ...
```

This frame can expand by passing time with more machines.
I need to make a R script where I have to get this solution:

```
workingTime, producedItems, MachineNum
```

Where MachineNum is the number in the column from where I get the data.(e.g. if I get Machine2.workingTime column and add to the new created column " workingTime " the "MachineNum" would be 2

I have to iterate through the whole `data.frame` and merging the columns into new columns which have the partial name of the old-original name(e.g. workingTime)
and filter the MachineNum from the first part of the old-original column name.

I tried and searched the last few hours but I could not find any solution.

Comment: Please provide a code example that includes your data frame (or made-up data similar to your data frame) and shows how far you got and where you got stuck.

Comment: It is not clear whethr these are column names or values in a column.  what is `MachineNum`

Comment: I think the keywords for you to search are long form versus wide form data and how to convert from on to the other. If you provide example data, you will probably get much better answers.

Comment: I have created a new Dataframe with the needed columns. So workingTime, producesItems, MachineNum and so on. I need to fill this frame now with the data from by big table where i have to filter by checking the column names. So I find out where to save by filtering the column name and comparing the String to the new columns names but I do not know how. Machine2.workingTime has to be filtered to "workingTime" and 2 to insert the value of this column to the new workingTime column and inserting 2 to machineNum column. And this has to be done for the whole tabel where i can get up to 1000 machines

Answer (score 0):

I think (hope) this is about what you are looking. I know my answer is not the most concise and look forward to see other cleaner answers.

```
library(data.table) # for melt() and merge(), other package have similar func.

# Dummy data.frame
df <- data.frame(date = Sys.Date() - 800:1, 
                 matrix(sample(0:10000, 2400), ncol = 6))
colnames(df)[-1] <- paste0("m", 1:3, c(rep(".wt", 3), rep(".pi", 3)))
head(df)
        date m1.wt m2.wt m3.wt m1.pi m2.pi m3.pi
1 2015-09-24  6271  2491  6525  6680  7708  2949
2 2015-09-25  1173  5794  5616  7402  3274  8997
3 2015-09-26   516  6659  2144  8739  7168  1704
4 2015-09-27   583  2499  4768  9501  2710  6800
5 2015-09-28  2433  8622  6492  7124  4127   233
6 2015-09-29  3409   662  6952  3824  5755  9479

# Now first take working time (filter using regex) to long form
df_wt <- melt(df[, c("date", grep("wt$", colnames(df), value = TRUE))],
              id.vars = c("date"),
              value.name = "workingTime",
              variable.name = "MachineNum")
df_wt$MachineNum <- gsub("m([0-9]).+", "\\1", df_wt$MachineNum)
head(df_wt)
        date MachineNum workingTime
1 2015-09-24          1        6271
2 2015-09-25          1        1173
3 2015-09-26          1         516
4 2015-09-27          1         583
5 2015-09-28          1        2433
6 2015-09-29          1        3409

# Same for produced item
df_pi <- melt(df[, c("date", grep("pi$", colnames(df), value = TRUE))],
              id.vars = c("date"),
              value.name = "producedItems",
              variable.name = "MachineNum")
df_pi$MachineNum <- gsub("m([0-9]).+", "\\1", df_pi$MachineNum)
head(df_pi)
        date MachineNum producedItems
1 2015-09-24          1          6680
2 2015-09-25          1          7402
3 2015-09-26          1          8739
4 2015-09-27          1          9501
5 2015-09-28          1          7124
6 2015-09-29          1          3824

# Now merge everything
df_long <- merge(df_wt, df_pi)
head(df_long)
        date MachineNum workingTime producedItems
1 2015-09-24          1        6271          6680
2 2015-09-24          2        2491          7708
3 2015-09-24          3        6525          2949
4 2015-09-25          1        1173          7402
5 2015-09-25          2        5794          3274
6 2015-09-25          3        5616          8997
```

Comment: df_wt$MachineNum <- gsub("m([0-9]).+", "\\1", df_wt$MachineNum) this does not seem to work. I get Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, testCaseNumber, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 8347837. Column name is Machine_01.workingTime and I do not need any date to use. so i tried it without id.vars=c("date") and got 1 column with workingTime of one machine only

Comment: If you don't have date I think you need some id variable to mark keep track of the observations...

Comment: Can I use the initial rownumber somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using the `reshape2` library.

```
machine1.workingTime <- 1:10
machine2.workingTime <- 21:30
machine1.producedItems <- 101:110
machine2.producedItems <- 201:210
date <- c("2017-01-01","2017-01-02","2017-01-03","2017-01-04","2017-01-05","2017-01-06",
          "2017-01-07","2017-01-08","2017-01-09","2017-01-10")


    theData <- data.frame(date,
                      machine1.producedItems,
                      machine1.workingTime,
                      machine2.producedItems,
                      machine2.workingTime
                      )

library(reshape2)

meltedData <- melt(theData,measure.vars=2:5)
meltedData$variable <- as.character(meltedData$variable)

# now, extract machine numbers and variable names
variableNames <- strsplit(as.character(meltedData$variable),"[.]")
# token after the . is variable name
meltedData$columnName <- unlist(lapply(variableNames,function(x) x[2]))
# since all variables start with word 'machine' we can set chars 8+ as ID
meltedData$machineId <- as.numeric(unlist(lapply(variableNames,function(x) y <- substr(x[1],8,nchar(x[1])))))

theResult <- dcast(meltedData,machineId + date ~ columnName,value.var="value")
head(theResult)
```

The results are:

```
> head(theResult)
  machineId       date producedItems workingTime
1         1 2017-01-01           101           1
2         1 2017-01-02           102           2
3         1 2017-01-03           103           3
4         1 2017-01-04           104           4
5         1 2017-01-05           105           5
6         1 2017-01-06           106           6
>
```

**UPDATE (02Dec2017):** Responding to the comments, if there is no other identifier to uniquely distinguish multiple rows for a machine, one can use an aggregation function to result in one observation per machine.

```
theResult <- dcast(meltedData,machineId ~ columnName,
                   fun.aggregate=mean,value.var="value")
head(theResult)
```

The results are as follows.

```
> head(theResult)
  machineId producedItems workingTime
1         1         105.5         5.5
2         2         205.5        25.5
>
```

**UPDATE (02Dec2017):**  responding to comments, a solution that uses a unique sequential number to distinguish rows of data looks like this.

```
machine1.workingTime <- 1:10
machine2.workingTime <- 21:30
machine1.producedItems <- 101:110
machine2.producedItems <- 201:210
id <- 1:length(machine1.workingTime)

theData <- data.frame(id,  
                      machine1.producedItems,
                      machine1.workingTime,
                      machine2.producedItems,
                      machine2.workingTime
)

meltedData <- melt(theData,measure.vars=2:5)
head(meltedData)
meltedData$variable <- as.character(meltedData$variable)

# now, extract machine numbers and variable names
variableNames <- strsplit(as.character(meltedData$variable),"[.]")
meltedData$columnName <- unlist(lapply(variableNames,function(x) x[2]))
meltedData$machineId <- as.numeric(unlist(lapply(variableNames,function(x) y <- substr(x[1],8,nchar(x[1])))))

theResult <- dcast(meltedData,machineId + id ~ columnName,value.var="value")
head(theResult)
```

...and the output.

```
head(theResult)
  machineId id producedItems workingTime
1         1  1           101           1
2         1  2           102           2
3         1  3           103           3
4         1  4           104           4
5         1  5           105           5
6         1  6           106           6
>
```

Comment: So, this seem to work till theResult <-dcast... I removes "+ date" since I do not need any date. But this do not work without date. The meltedData seems correct. Just need to wrap it from long formated data to short formated data!? It does not seem to work without a unique value in place of date!?

Comment: @Rnooby - Unless there is only one row in the data frame, you'll need some way to distinguish multiple rows in the output from `dcast()`. The solution from @snoram highlights the same issue: you'll need some sort of ID variable to distinguish multiple rows for each machine ID, or you'll need to use an aggregation function  like `sum()` or `mean()`.

Comment: Can I use the initial rownumber somehow? I am very new to R and this is kinda hard to figure out by myself. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @Rnooby would you please use `dput()` to post some of your data in your question so we can see the inputs? Then we can help you get the right result. Also, please upvote / accept the answers if you're finding them helpful.

Comment: I can not post the Data but I can describe how the melted Data looks like. column names: variable, value, columnName, machineNumber. variable and columnName are almost the same. variables are like Machine_01.workingTime and so on. coulumnNames are workingTime and so on. this looks great up till here. I have to bring them together in a table which looks like this: MachineNumber, workingTime, vibrationRate, producedItems, (and all other columnNames as columns) But there is no unique field. there can be dublicated in every row. so row 1 can have same values as row 2, 3 and so on.

Comment: @Rnooby the last update to my answer shows how to avoid the duplicate rows by setting a column `id` equal to row number.